# lodash returning false for object containing JSX elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I am using `lodash` `isEqual` function for checking `prevProps` and `newProps` in `componentWillReceiveProps`.

`if(!isEqual(this.props.data, newProps.data))
  //code to be run with new data`

Above check always returns `false` when my object contains `JSX` element. It seems that `isEqual` is not able to figure out that `JSX` elements are same. Due to this, performance is impacted.

I googled regarding this problem but could not find anything useful.

Note: `data` is array of object.

Sample Data:

```
[{"type":"regular","id":"edd76f60-eb2f-11e9-bfd3-01322f05fe43","indicator":"53930-3-2"},
{"type":"regular 1","id":"fdd76f60-eb2f-11e9-bfd3-01322f05fe43","indicator":{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), ...} }]
```

When i am trying to print data with `JSON.stringify`, it is giving below error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'ReactCompositeComponentWrapper'
    |     property '_instance' -> object with constructor 'StatelessComponent'
    --- property '_reactInternalInstance' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:6`.

I don't know but i think `circular structure` is the reason that it is returning `false`.

Comment: Can you give an example of what `this.props.data` and `newProps.data` contain?

Comment: @VLAZ i added sample data

Answer (score 0):

```
let firstObject = {"type":"regular","id":"edd76f60-eb2f-11e9-bfd3-01322f05fe43","indicator":"53930-3-2"};
let secondObject = {"type":"regular","id":"edd76f60-eb2f-11e9-bfd3-01322f05fe43","indicator":"53930-3-2"};
 
_.isEqual(firstObject, secondObject);
```